Flutter's Android Apps white out on the second run or later, if without the Emulator's 'Wipe Data'
The app ran well the first time with no problem. But then when I stopped the program and ran it again, the emulator failed to launch the app and whited out like the following picture, without throwing any errors.

Console:
Launching lib\\main.dart on sdk gphone16k x86 64 in debug mode...

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

√ Built build\\app\\outputs\\flutter-apk\\app-debug.apk

Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53998/JPrAPAtzNX8=/ws

Syncing files to device sdk gphone16k x86 64...

I/le.test_project( 7228): Compiler allocated 5174KB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()

Result of flutter doctor -v as follows:
PS D:\Development\flutter\test_project> flutter doctor -v
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3958], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.22.3 on channel stable at C:\Users\BlueZ\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision b0850beeb2 (10 days ago), 2024-07-16 21:43:41 -0700
    • Engine revision 235db911ba
    • Dart version 3.4.4
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\BlueZ\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jbr\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[√] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.10.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.10.35013.160
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22621.0

[√] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0--11852314)

[√] VS Code (version 1.91.1)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\BlueZ\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[√] Connected device (3 available)
    • Windows (desktop) • windows • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.3958]
    • Chrome (web)      • chrome  • web-javascript • Google Chrome 127.0.6533.72
    • Edge (web)        • edge    • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 127.0.2651.74

[√] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

If I 'Wipe Data' the emulator, it runs fine again, but if not, it fails.
I made new Flutter projects (default counter) and the problem happened to them too. But it didn't happen to Java default projects. So I guess it's caused by flutter projects' settings or sth.
'Invalidate Caches...' didn't change a thing.
I tried migrating gradle files to a new syntax according to this link:
https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/flutter-gradle-plugin-apply
I also went to 'Project Structure' => 'SDK' and set it to 'Android API 35, extension level 13 Platform' which is the emulator I'm using currently. Not a change.
I reinstalled Flutter SDK / Java JDK / Android Studio, with any personal settings. Didn't work.
It's annoying and inefficient having to 'Wipe Data' the emulator every time I run an app.
No idea how to solve it. Any advice would help. Thanks in advance.

I experienced the same issue.
Please check if disabling hardware acceleration and starting the application resolves the issue:
flutter run --enable-software-rendering

This issue is probably the same as the one being discussed in this thread:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/146890
When placing a button, it is not visible but can be tapped, so it seems to be an emulator rendering issue.
I decided to choose 'ANGLE' in the emulator settings to fix the hardware acceleration.
I decided to choose 'ANGLE' in the emulator settings to use the software acceleration.
Android Emulator setting Dialog
In the emulator toolbox, go to '...' → Settings → Advanced tab → set OpenGL ES renderer to 'ANGLE(D3D11)' and restart the emulator.
Note:
Selecting hardware acceleration worked on first run, but the issue reoccurred after uninstalling and reinstalling the app.
It does not reoccur with software acceleration.
Other solutions from this thread:

Revert the emulator to an older version without the bug

